# Mouseover in WPF is driving me Nuts

Tags: wpf, triggers, styles

I am trying to learn WPF, so please don't hammer me for asking what I suspect is a really stupid question, but I have spent several days trawling the web for answers, but nothing seems to overcome my problem.

Basically, All I am trying to do is to learn about Styles for my various test app Controls to get the hang of what works best, and how to use them. I have specified a Style named "simpler" Style declared in the 'Page.Resources'.

The first section of the Style for Background does work correctly and my button has a Gradient fill as expected,  however, Despite my best efforts over days of trial and error (Mostly Error), I still cannot get the 'IsMouseOver' Trigger to do anything at all.  indeed almost any other "Event" that requires a trigger to be called refuse totally to do anything.

It just seems that the entire '<Style.Triggers>' section of my Style are simply ignored by WPF ?

I woulld really appreciate someone explaining to me, in simplish terms, why this is happening, or rather, not happening, and how I can get it to work ?

Thanks in Advance.
'''

```
 Title="Page1">
<Page.Resources>
    <Style  x:Key="mouseover"
        TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="simpler" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD190" Offset="0.35"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.95"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD190" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" >
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD190" Offset="0.35"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.95"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD190" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>

</Page.Resources>
<!--xmlns:Models="clr-namespace:WpfUI.Models"-->
<Grid>

    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.972"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    <WrapPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
             Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
             Grid.RowSpan="1" Height="60">
        
        <!--Button ONE-->
        <Button 
            x:Name="btn1"
            Height="50" Width="135" 
            Margin="5"
            Click="Page1_Click"
            Foreground="White"
            Content="ewttwttrt"
            Style="{StaticResource simpler}">
            
            <!-- We put our "text" into a Stackpanel (or any similar control)
            so that we can use the defined Template above, whch stops our 
            text from being rendered -->
            <!--<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock FontFamily="Wingdings" FontSize="16" Text="ü"/>
                <TextBlock Text="btn1-MyButtonTemplate"/>
            </StackPanel>-->
        </Button>
```

'''

Comment: Sorry to say that, but it is a little more complicated than just setting the Background property. There is a VisualState in place that sets the Background property of an element in the Button's ControlTemplate. See [Button Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/button-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). You would need to replace the ControlTemplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure SO is really so well suited to beginners.

Later on.
You might find this interesting:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32610.wpf-layout-lab.aspx

First though.
Create a new wpf app.
Throw a button in the grid inside your mainwindow.
It fills your grid but don't worry about that.

Spin it up.
Mouse over.
See it turns light blue?
It isn't the background that does that.
It's something on top of the background.

Try pasting this in, over everything below your opening window tag.

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="simpler" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD190" Offset="0.35"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.95"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD190" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="2"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" >
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD190" Offset="0.35"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.95"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD190" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Width="1155" Height="805">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource simpler}">
            Banana
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks SO Much - It works, but more importantly it has taught me to be really wary of WPF, it seems it loves to make things far more complex than they really should be.

Comment: While on this subject, I have an ellipse acting as a button. The background is painted by a style, and the mouseover now also works (using  modified code from above) but the TextBlock that is used to show text on the Ellipse "blocks the Mouseover event the Ellipse is seeing.  Is there a way to perhaps "pass" the mouseover event of the TextBlock thru to the host Ellipse in any way so the background animation is not interrupted  by the mouse crossing into the TextBlock that is logically on top of the Ellipse itself and stopping  the  Ellipses mouseover handling ??

Comment: WPF is very flexible. In order to be that flexible it works in ways look more complicated than you might expect.   A button is a contentcontrol. You can put anything you like in it. Explicitly put a textblock in your button and set ishittestvisible to false on it.  Also. Don't think of SO as a discussion forum, or you're headed for disappointment. If someone posts an answer to your question you should mark their post as answer. If you think it's particularly helpful as well you can upvote.

Comment: Thanks Andy, your comments are fully noted and I understand. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry  about this, but to save wasting any of your valuable time, I have just discovered the PreviewMouseDown Property, which lets me get around the problem I describe above for any  control that does not support the Click event, so no need to waste time answering this, unless of course, you have a better solution ??